# playing around with py2app

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I was playing around with py2app on Snow Leopard(10.6) and I'm running into a few problems when I run

`python setup.py py2app`

I get the following error :-

```
% python setup.py py2app
running py2app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/py2app-0.7.3-py2.6.egg/py2app/build_app.py", line 502, in run
    if sysconfig.get_config_var('PYTHONFRAMEWORK') is None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_config_var'
```

I had installed py2app as per the documentation [here](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html#abstract), however it seems there are a few environment variables that I haven't set. I also tried cloning a few projects, like the one [here](https://github.com/astrofrog/py2app-experiments) and I end up with the same error.

Could someone point me to the documentation that mentioned how I'm supposed to configure py2app before use? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That py2app documentation is ancient; what you should be using is [here](http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/).

As you can see from the stack trace you pasted, something is causing `distutils.sysconfig` to be `None`.  It looks like you're using the system versions of Python and distutils, which work just fine for me on 10.6.8:

```
% /usr/bin/python -c "from distutils import sysconfig; print sysconfig.get_config_var('PYTHONFRAMEWORK')"
Python
```

So if you get a different result from above, you could start there, otherwise you can start debugging the py2app code to see why `sysconfig` is `None`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in py2app, a quick workaround: in build_app.py (see the traceback in the question for its location) at line 25 change "sysconfig = None" to "from distutils import sysconfig".

I've filed an issue in py2app's tracker[1] and will do a new release soonish (once I've had time to create and test a patch).

[1] https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/issue/96/py2app-doesnt-work-with-python-26-anymore